# Angular dependecy injection via $inject

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

In my Angular application, I inject the dependencies in my controller in the following way:

```
function ProcessController ( WidgetService, $scope, $http, $state, SessionService, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $stateParams, CommonService ) 
{
    ...
}

ProcessController.$inject = [ 'WidgetService', '$scope', '$http', '$state', 'SessionService', '$mdToast', '$mdDialog', '$stateParams', 'CommonService' ];  
angular.module ( 'core' ).controller ( 'ProcessController', ProcessController );
```

In some of the controllers, it works well but in some of them the dependencies are not recognised. So if I change it to like this, it works well again.

```
function ProcessController(WidgetService,$scope,$http,$state, SessionService,$mdToast,$mdDialog,$stateParams,CommonService) 
{
    ...
}

angular.module ('core').controller (['WidgetService','$scope','$http','$state','SessionService','$mdToast','$mdDialog','$stateParams','CommonService',ProcessController]);
```

So I want to know why is my dependency injection with `$inject` is failing?

One of the use case that I encountered was, by using the first method I get `$stateParams` as `undefined` in the controller but if I use the second method, I get the required data in it.

Comment: Can you please provide an example that will illustrate the issue?

Comment: try `angular.module( 'core',[ ])` instead of  `angular.module ( 'core')`.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce it on jsFiddle. Also, I have multiple controllers that work fine with the first method. There are just couple of them which showcase the issue.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I tried it, but it breaks my rest of the code.

Comment: try defining your module then: `var app = angular.module('core',[]);` and use that variable to bind controllers: `app.controller('ProcessController', ProcessController);`

Comment: Since you mention it works in some but not in others, I suspect that some of the dependencies aren't properly defined or are not registered to the same module.  Your code, as it appears here, should work.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey tried that too. Still the same.

Comment: @ryanyuyu As of now, there's only one module in my application, `core`. So as the same dependencies are working on other controllers, there's no issue of unregistered dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in order

Define / Declare module

Declare controller to angular

Inject dependencies

Define controller

Rule of thumb inject should be after you declare your controller to angular

```
 function ProcessController ( WidgetService, $scope, $http, $state, SessionService, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $stateParams, CommonService ) {
   ...
}

 angular.module ( 'core' ).controller ( 'ProcessController', ProcessController );

ProcessController.$inject = [ 'WidgetService', '$scope', '$http', '$state', 'SessionService', '$mdToast', '$mdDialog', '$stateParams', 'CommonService' ];
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify controller's name:

```
angular.module ('core')
.controller('ProcessController',['WidgetService', ...,'CommonService',ProcessController]);
```